# Why is my localStorage clear on redirect (URL change)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage

I am trying to persist data between pages, a variable that I collect in my URL. So my user will enter a URL like: https://my-solution/event/:identifier
I want to keep that identifier but I need to go through authentication first. I store my identifier in the local storage or Session storage before the redirection and when I redirect to https://my-solution/auth, this entry disappear from local storage.

Once the auth succeed and I store my user jwt token in this very same local storage, it persists ! My identifier is been deleted but my token persist (and every variable stored after that btw); After my token is being stored I can redirect all I want, and my data persist. I don't understand what's happening...
It is a create-react-app solution. Working with react-router and redux.
Is this linked to the way I redirect ? I use `<Redirect>` from react-router but also `windows.location.href` sometimes (inside useEffect callbacks).

I did tried to store a non-dynamic variable like a basic string :

```
localStorage.setItem("test", "mytestValue")
```

And this entry does persists. Is this behavior related to dynamic values ?

I do have a complicated workaround : passing the data through location.search in every url and trying in every component to store it until the data persists in the local storage... But I want to know if I am doing something wrong here.
Thank you !
Here is my architecture flow :

Index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';

import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { signalRMiddleware } from './middlewares/signalRMiddleware';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'primereact/resources/themes/nova/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

const store = process.env.REACT_APP_WITHOUT_SIGNALR == "true" ? createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)) : createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, signalRMiddleware()))
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Router from './components/Router';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
moment().locale('fr');

function App() {
  return (
      <Router />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Router.index

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';
import UtilsService from '../../services/utils.service';

function Router() {
    const AuthRouters = UtilsService.getRoute('/auth').component;
    const BackofficeRouters = UtilsService.getRoute('/backoffice').component;
    const EventLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/').component;
    const MultiEventLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/multiEvents').component;
    const ChatLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/chat').component;
    const ChatOtoLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/chat_oto').component;
    const QuestionsLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/questions').component;
    const PlanningLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/planning').component;
    const AccueilMobileLayout = UtilsService.getRoute('/accueil_mobile').component;

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/auth" render={(props: any) => <AuthRouters {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/backoffice" isBackoffice={true} render={(props: any) => <BackofficeRouters {...props} exact />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/multiEvents" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <MultiEventLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/room/:id" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <EventLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/event/:identifier" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <EventLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/questions/:idButton" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <QuestionsLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/chat_oto" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <ChatOtoLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/chat/:id" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <ChatLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/planning/:idEvent" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <PlanningLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/accueil_mobile/:idEvent" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <AccueilMobileLayout {...props} />} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/" isBackoffice={false} render={(props: any) => <EventLayout {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default Router;
```

ProtectedRoute.tsx

```
return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                let eventUrlIdentifier = "";
                if(props.match.path === "/event/:identifier"){
                    let url = props.match.url;
                    let s = url.split("/");
                    eventUrlIdentifier = s[2];
                }
                if (!fetchAllConfLoading && isClientSettingsLoaded) {
                    //process auth anonymous
                    if (user == null) {
                        if (clientSettings.monoEventId != undefined && clientSettings.allowAnonymous != undefined) {
                            if (!clientSettings.allowAnonymous) {
                                // Redirection vers /Auth si la connexion anonyme n'est pas autorisé pour un mono-event
                                return (
                                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/Auth', state: { from: props.location }, search: eventUrlIdentifier }} />
                                );
                            }
                            else {
                                return (
                                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/auth/anonyme', state: { from: props.location }, search: eventUrlIdentifier }} />
                                );
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

session storage and local storage will remain only for the same domain. If domain changes then, the values stored in either one of them will be gone. Work around for this to use cookies to store data between two pages of different domains.